# react-native-navigation update child data but remain parent data

Tags: react-native, wix-react-native-navigation

I having problem when I push to next screen.

Lets say from screen A(product details screen) -> screen B(product details screen)

Currently I am successfully move from screen A to screen B. But the problems is when i navigate back to screen A, the data in screen A already updated which is same as screen B.

Below is how i update my screen data by using componentDidMount() and navigate to next screen using push.

```
componentDidMount() { 
    this.props.getDetails(id);
}
this.props.navigator.push({
    screen:'myapp.productDetailsScreen'
})
```

Is it something i missed that accidentally update screen a data when i navigate to screen b?

Screen A and Screen B share the same component (they just render different value based on the id given).

I am using this library

[react-native-navigation v1](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation) (wix)

Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using redux you the redux state between both of the screens is shared. that is why it is updated on both screens.

Comment: then how am i suppose to do like that ? (I am using redux) Any recommend idea will be appreciated!!

Comment: what you can do is don't put this response in redux at all.
you can return data directly from redux, or create a new data structure to handle all the items in it. maybe an array..

Comment: Thank you so much for making me become more clearer about how those data flow between component and redux! Really appreciated your help!!